# GridFS random access

Tags: mongodb, blob, random-access, nosql

Is it possible to have random access for reads and writes in mongo?

Comment: What other kind of access would there be?

Comment: Many similar file in database systems are either append only or require that the entire document be rewritten if it is changed.  This is not the case with MongoDB's GridFS system.  The question is a legitimate one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to have random access with document (chunk) granularity (it's 256k by default). You can read/write these blocks independently.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. MongoDB allows reading and writing of documents (and thus files) in any order.

Answer (score 0):

GridFS file metadata and chunks are stored in regular collections (usually called fs.files and fs.chunks). At a very low level you could read and write these documents yourself if you wanted too. Some drivers provide a stream like interface to GridFS files, including random access. Which driver are you using?